# How do we check if a browser's auto-update is enabled through javascript

Tags: javascript, browser

I want to check form the javascript if a browser's auto-update is enabled.

The reason I want this is that our software supports only a set of Browser versions and we want to alert them if auto-update is on.

Is there any way we can do this?

Abhi

Answer (score 3):

No. Browsers are highly sand-boxed and will give you almost no information about the users system.

You'll instead have to just do something like check the version and alert them if it isn't up-to-date, with maybe some information on how to check if they have auto-updated turned on.

Comment: *"...and alert them if it isn't up-to-date..."* Or rather, if it isn't on their list of supported versions. But doing this at all is a massive maintenance hassle.

Comment: Indeed. It's best to just stick with reasonable standards and degrade gracefully instead... but that wasn't the question. ;)

Comment: Another approach is to use something like Modernizr to check for specific *features* needed and alert when a required feature isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you require a set version, but one thing to do is check if the browser supports a specific method (One that your app requires).

If not, tell them to update their browser. This example test if the user has WebSockets:

```js
if (window.WebSocket) {
  alert("BROWSER SUPPORTED");
} else {
  alert("BROWSER NOT SUPPORTED");
}
```